# In the movie “Momentum” why is the airport Western Cape International Airport?

Tags: film-location, momentum

In the movie *[Momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_(2015_film))* why is the airport named Western Cape International Airport? There’s no such airport. The city of Cape Town is indeed in the Western Cape province. But the main airport is Cape Town International Airport. Just seemed strange that they would use a real city, film on location, but use a fictitious airport name.

Comment: Sounds like a rights issue. Perhaps the airport would not give permission to use the name.

Comment: Didn't know that permission was required. Still seems unlikely though, because I saw the Department of Trade and Industry in the credits.

Comment: Although Cape Town International is majority owned by the South African government the Company is legally and financially autonomous and operates under commercial law. So, if they think something in the movie (I haven't seen it, so I don't know) might reflect badly on their image they might withhold permission

Comment: Sounds plausible, hadn't thought of that, thank you.